# Returning a List or IEnumerable with IHttpActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to return a list of a certain object with my `IHttpActionResult` method, returning a single instance of that object is easily done by using `return Ok(new object {});`. However when adding a preset single object or list it results in:

> "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'."

I checked if the content of the list/object was correct which it was, and returning a single instance of this object as a new object does work. Does anyone know how I can return a list or IEnumerable in this way, or in another way?

Code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/v1/GetArticles/{code}/{companycode}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetArticles(int code, string companycode)
{
    BusinessLogic.Database.DbEntity dc = new BusinessLogic.Database.DbEntity();
    try
    {
        if (companycode.Equals("null", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
          List<BusinessLogic.Database.Item> items = ItemEntity.GetItems(code, null, dc);
          return Ok(items);
        }
        else
        {
            List<BusinessLogic.Database.Item> items = ItemEntity.GetItems(code, companycode, dc);
            return Ok(items);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Working single instance:

```
BusinessLogic.Database.Item item = ListEntity.GetItem(code, null, dc);

//Does not work
//return Ok(item);

//Works
return Ok(new BusinessLogic.Database.Item {
  Name = item.Name,
  Code = item.Code
});
```